# Passing object as parameter for constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I have 3 classes. These classes are Class1, Parent and Child. I'm having some trouble to figure out how to write a constructor I need for my Child class.

```
public Class1
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Class1()
    {
    firstName="";
    lastName="";
    }

    public Class1(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
    }

    //Methods and stuff
}
```

---

```
public Parent
{
    private Class1 class1;
    private double number;

    public Parent();
    {
    class1=new Class1();
    number=0;
    }

    public Parent(Class1 c, double n)
    {
    Class1=c;
    number=n;
    }

//Methods and stuff
}
```

---

```
public Child extends Parent
{
    private String string;
    private Boolean boolean;

    public Child(Class1 class1, double n, String s, Boolean b)
    {
    //Don't know how to get the Class1 part to work
    //Don't know how to get the double to work
    string=s;
    boolean=b;

//Methods and stuff
}
```

I don't know how to write the code so that I can get my constructor to take the arguments like this:

```
new Child(new Class1("String", "String"), 10, "String", true);
```

I hope this helps clarify what my problem is.

Comment: you will have to state your inheritance hierarchy again because so far it seems to be incorrect to me ...

Comment: ... and please write Java instead of English ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Child` constructor as

```
public Child(Class1 objClass1, double number, string str, boolean bool){
    super(objClass1,number);
    this.str=str;
    this.bool=bool;
}
```

Create `Parent` constructor as

```
public Parent(Class1 objClass1, double number){
    this.objClass1=objClass1;
    this.number=number;
}
```

and you can called the child constructor as

```
Child objChild=new Child(new Class1(str1,str2),number,str,bool);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you the code, because you've not given us enough information, but let's assume you've got a class structure like..

```
 public class Parent
 {
     private String field;

     public Parent(String field) {
         this.field = field;
     }
 }

 public class Child extends Parent {
     private String field;

     public Child(String field)
     {
         this.field = field;
     }
 }
```

What you can do is specify a constructor in your `Child` class that passes the variables up the inheritance chain, to your `Parent` class:

```
public Child(String field, String parentField)
{
     super(parentField); // Calls the parent class.
     this(field);
}
```

So what you've done there, is passed the `parentField` up to the `Parent` class, and you've called your existing constructor that accepts a single `String` parameter.

Apply this principle to your code and you'll get it in minutes.